Sending USDC from Safe Multisig by interacting directly with Smart Contracts
I need to transfer ERC20 assets from Safe multisig wallet to another address by interacting directly with the contracts.
I understand that I need to call execTransaction on GnosisSafeProxy contract. I assume that data for the transaction should be encoded call to usdc.transferFrom(from, to, value) method.
My multisig wallet is 2/4 signatures, and I am not sure how to group signatures from multiple wallets in order to fill signatures argument for execTransaction call.
Can anyone help me out, or point me to the proper tutorial/explanation?
Thanks!
